# How to create a 500 error on an rest API for error testing purpose?

Tags: node.js, rest, testing, chai

I am writing some test code for my rest api using nodejs and chai.

I would like to create a 500 error on purpose to be sure my API react well, but I have no idea on how to do that.

Any help or tips about best practices would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this URL, this is dedicated for testing purpose :

https://httpstat.us/500

Or expose a php script with garbage in it, like :

```
<?php

foobarbase
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following syntax:
res.status(500).json({your message});